# Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a successfully running WCF service that I can call using javascript. However I want to invoke it using the WCF test client and im having difficulty doing this. I am told that I need to make sure I have enabled meta data publishing at the specified address. After reading the documentation I just cant see what im meant to do this is my configuration:

```xml
    <system.serviceModel>
       <services>
           <service name="CommentSessionIDWCFService" 
                    behaviorConfiguration="CommentSessionIDBehavior">
              <endpoint 
                  address="" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="CountryProvinceBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="ICommentSessionIDWCFService" />
           </service>
       </services>
       <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
             <behavior name="CommentSessionIDBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
             </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
              <behavior name="CountryProvinceBehavior">
                  <webHttp/>
              </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I've read other posts but I can't see what to populate and I just keep getting errors. Q's..

1. Am I right in saying that I need to configure a complete new service in my config to show the metadata?
2. What do I add to the configuration to make this meta data published so I can invoke with the client?

Comment: thanks for editing mark how did you neaten it? The tab button doesnt work for me...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need a metadata endpoint for your service, here`s an example.

```xml
<services>
    <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MEX">
    <endpoint
        address="http://localhost:8000/MEX"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        contract="IMetadataExchange"
    />
    </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MEX">
            <serviceMetadata/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: is this all I need to do? What does http://localhost:8000/MEX physically point to?

Comment: it adds a endpoint on the server that listens on port 8000 for metadata requests based on the IMetadataExchange contract. it responds with the data needed to build a proxy to the service. VS uses this data when you do an 'add reference' operation.

Comment: whomever down-voted this answer, please provide a reason for doing so.

Comment: mine as well (+1)

Comment: @Menahem I have the same problem: where should I add the lines of codes you provided?
In the app.config of my Proxy I have these:
'
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
'
Should I edit the contract value?

Comment: Hi @franz1 , the configuration in the answer is for the service side. The contract that you have '"ServiceReference1.IService1' is probably OK, and contains the operations you need for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after changing the config file in the TestClient with right click and "edit with svceditor" to increase my maxbuffersize. If someone did that mistake as well, try rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 0):

Add

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]

Answer (score -1):

Set `httpGetEnabled` to `true` and set the `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` to `false`:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
```