# WCF Webservice Cannot Run as Windows Application

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

In VS 2013 I have my first WCF web service, the web service is functioning correctly as a Class Library, when I attempt to ready the application to deploy as a managed windows service I modify the output type to Windows Application. Running the application in the test client provides the error:

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from [SERVICE URL OMITTED] If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing

Answer (score 0):

I think that is about the endpoint of your service.

Check this answer and maybe you will be able to find the answer here:

[Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056329/error-cannot-obtain-metadata-from-wcf-service)

I hope this helps