# Having issue trying to Add Service Reference in C# WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl

SSL is used. Client and Server Certificates are generated and signed by self-signed CA. Successfully opens in browser Chrome and Opera after authentication.
svcutil says:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://212.112.97.194:7777/Service1.svc?wsdl

WS-Metadata Exchange Error
    URI: https://212.112.97.194:7777/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056329/error-cannot-obtain-metadata-from-wcf-service

Comment: Sajeetharan,but it is for unsafe communications. I need safe metadata exchange.