# Microsoft WCF test client Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am new to WCF services. I was browsing with some tutorials and got a simple program and tried to execute in WCF service application in c#. The code is shown below.

IService1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        int calculatedays(int day,int month,int year);
    }    
}
```

Service1.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

 namespace WcfService1
 {
     public class Service1 : IService1
     {
         public int calculatedays(int day, int month, int year)
         {
             DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
             int datetodays = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).Days;
             return datetodays;
         }  
     }
}
```

web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
   <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

when i run the application its giving the error as

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:2049/Service1.svc
>   If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at
>   the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please
>   refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: http://localhost:2049/Service1.svc    Metadata contains
>   a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:2049/Service1.svc'.    The server did not provide a
>   meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a
>   premature session shutdown or an internal server error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from WCF service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056329/error-cannot-obtain-metadata-from-wcf-service)

Comment: How are you hosting the WCF service, can we see that code too

Comment: you have not set your interface method signature to have the OperationContract attribute also...

Answer (score 2):

Create One Host and add appconfig file inside the host program.Then write the following code inside appconfig.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="maxBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="WcfService1" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
        </endpoint>


        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:2049/"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="maxBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Add Reference of the Wcfservice1 project to this project.create one class and write the following code

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfService1.Service1)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Started Report Host");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```